# how can i solve this error? Error Code: 0x00000004 (no mapping for user data read), I made the app , thanks

Tags: python, macos, pyautogui, py2app

I made the app in python and converted it into an app for macos with py2app, on my mac it works correctly but on another mac the error "Error Code: 0x00000004 (no mapping for user data read)" appears. I have already read some articles but they always say to update the app but this solution does not work for me because I made the app, I leave the LOG for you to analyze, thanks. I just discovered that they only allow 30 thousand characters here so I can't upload the full log.

```
Process:               Scriptmac [21365]
Path:                  /Applications/Scriptmac.app/Contents/MacOS/Scriptmac
Identifier:            org.pythonmac.unspecified.Scriptmac
Version:               0.0.0 (0.0.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Scriptmac [21365]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-03-04 15:44:49.548 -0300
OS Version:            macOS 11.6.2 (20G314)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     6.1 (19P647)
Anonymous UUID:        5F689581-B413-BD01-6664-70AD629718FA

Sleep/Wake UUID:       661F72DA-3DD0-4213-A381-BEDB59CD7C9E

Time Awake Since Boot: 170000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       67000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [21365]

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                      1022a1000-1022a9000    [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Applications/Scriptmac.app/Contents/MacOS/Scriptmac

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20609775 CFStringGetCString + 57
1   org.pythonmac.unspecified.Scriptmac 0x00000001022a5aad py2app_main + 4433
2   org.pythonmac.unspecified.Scriptmac 0x00000001022a4357 main + 257
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff205a4f3d start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20585420 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff20585420 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x30ef29f9f71700c0  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000008000100  rdx: 0x0000000000000400
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x00007ffeed95d910  rbp: 0x00007ffeed95c810  rsp: 0x00007ffeed95c7d0
   r8: 0x0000000000000370   r9: 0x0000000000000050  r10: 0x00000000000007fb  r11: 0x00000000000000cc
  r12: 0x0000000000000400  r13: 0x000060000093c410  r14: 0x00007ffeed95d910  r15: 0x0000000008000100
  rip: 0x00007fff20609775  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000000
  
Logical CPU:     6
Error Code:      0x00000004 (no mapping for user data read)
Trap Number:     14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "no mapping for user data read" is a common error on mac when running apps. This usually happens if your software version on mac is either outdated or too modern.

Here are the steps I suggest:

1. First Check the versions of each mac by clicking the  logo in the top left of your mac and selecting "about this mac".
2. If the current software version is not the same for each mac, upgrade or downgrade the other mac's software to the one of which the app worked on.
3. To upgrade, click the  logo in the top left of your mac > system preferences > software update.
4. To downgrade, refer to this [link](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/install-old-mac-os-3679956/)